# A ThreadLocal Supplier?

Tags: java, java-8

If I need a ThreadLocal of a variable, is there a need to also use Supplier (also thread-safe)?

For example, isn't the Supplier unnecessary to accomplish thread-safety here?

```
private ThreadLocal<Supplier<MyClass>> myObject = new ThreadLocal<Supplier<MyClass>>();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question doesn't show the typical way to use a Supplier with a ThreadLocal.  If you want a ThreadLocal of MyClass, the old (pre-1.8) way to do that was typically:

```
ThreadLocal<MyClass> local = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>();

// later
if (local.get() == null) {
  local.put(new MyClass());
}
MyClass myClass = local.get();
```

The alternative was to delcare a subclass of `ThreadLocal` that overrode the `initialValue` method.

In 1.8, you can instead use a Supplier to handle that initialization:

```
ThreadLocal<MyClass> local = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new MyClass());
```

Functionally, these two are basically identical, but the Supplier version is a lot less code to write.

Comment: You can write it even shorter by replacing `() -> new MyClass()` with `MyClass::new`.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know you could use that syntax for constructors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the Supplier class is returned.

**It needs to be synchronized in these cases:**

- Lets says it is maintaining some state between every creation, it needs to be thread safe. i.e, need to synchronize on Supplier.get() method.
- If you are fetching the returned object from cache.

**It need not be synchronized in these cases:**

- If it is simpler factory that always creates and returns the object.

In both cases, **MyClass need not be synchronized**. Because it is always local to thread.

Comment: Thanks. Can't I just remove the Supplier and the MyClass object would still be thread-safe?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I can help. I think I can explain 2 questions you have: one is does threadlocal solve "thread safe"? another is what function does supplier provide.

To answer first question:
Actually, threadlocal does not guarantee "thread safe". Threadlocal only keeps thread access to its own copy of threadlocal value. Typically, it is used to maintain the context message used across several methods invoked in the same thread.

To answer decond question:
In short, using "ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new MyClass())" to create an instance of  ThreadLocal, every first time you invoke get() method of threadlocal variable in a new thread you will get value created by the supplier function "() -> new MyClass()".

With more details:
This "withInitial" method actually returns an instance of SuppliedThreadLocal which extends ThreadLocal.

Here is the source code of SuppliedThreadLocal:

```
static final class SuppliedThreadLocal<T> extends ThreadLocal<T> {

    private final Supplier<? extends T> supplier;

    SuppliedThreadLocal(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = Objects.requireNonNull(supplier);
    }

    @Override
    protected T initialValue() {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

We can see it overrides initialValue method to return the variable created by supplier.

Where is "initialValue()" method used ?

In get() method of Threadlocal instance, setInitialValue is invoked and initialValue() will be invoked there.

```
public T get() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null) {
        ThreadLocalMap.Entry e = map.getEntry(this);
        if (e != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T result = (T)e.value;
            return result;
        }
    }
    return setInitialValue();
}
private T setInitialValue() {
    T value = initialValue();
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null)
        map.set(this, value);
    else
        createMap(t, value);
    return value;
}
```

This means when current thread does not hold the value in the current thread's copy of this thread-local variable, supplier function will be invoked here to create new variable.

Hope this helps.